# How to prevent my margins from collapsing?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

**The problem:**

I have two divs that have the same css but for some reason the first div **gets** a margin left but the second one **does not**.

[image]

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/surgvtz3/)

Code: 
I am using bootstrap but besides that I have these two css rules that should give me the desired margin.

```
.main {
    padding-right: 40px;
    padding-left: 40px;
}

.marginLeftM {
    margin-left: 30px
}
```

I am aware of that the margins are collapsing but I do not know how to solve it.

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't work for me... I see errors in the JS console: `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Comment: it's because your cols are floated left - clear left and they will have the same margin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `navbar-header` element above the first of those DIVs, there's a `padding-left` of 33px (directly in the HTML code). If you remove that, your DIVs line up vertically

https://jsfiddle.net/zbxj63ou/

Comment: Both answers here are correct. I will be accepting this one since It made me realize to remove code that should not have been there. I am using both answers.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Your first div gets extra margin so Please add the CSS.

```
.marginLeftM {
 margin-left: 30px;
 clear: both;
 }
```

Comment: Both answers here are correct. I will be accepting the other once since It made me realize to remove code that should not have been there. I am using both answers.

Thank you!